# No internet from one AP

Tags: wi-fi, networking, dns, dhcp

I have four Asus APs throughout my home, with the same two SSIDs, one for 2.4 and one for 5GHz. If I connect my Android device to the 5GHz band, then it works fine on 3 APs until it roams to one of the APs (kitchen), after which it fails to find internet. If I forget the network and then join it anew, it works till it roams back to kitchen from another AP. It also works fine on the 2.4 band.
All other devices, fixed and roaming, work fine.
I have fully reset network settings on Android, set static IP and 8.8.8.8 DNS, have reset the AP in the kitchen and also reset the AP that is connected to the gateway and is serving DHCP. I changed the SSID to something different and it worked on that AP, but that's not a permanent solution and it's a pain to change them throughout and reconnect so many devices, and may not even work.

Comment: What Android device are you talking about? Please post device model name and manufacturer. Do you have other Android devices that work on the kitchen AP?

Comment: Hi, it's an Honor Magic5 Pro. Only other Android device I have is a Fire tablet (seldom used). Will try that tomorrow. Thanks for suggestion!

Comment: Please edit the question to provide more information.  Perhaps that particular AP is defective.  I am not sure whether its an Android issue at all.